# How to cite an image, created from other (non CC) images?

Tags: citations

I want to include an image that contains 4-5 graphs from diverse sources next to each other, in order to illustrate their similarities. Since I do not own any of those images I want to include, how do I properly cite them?

Comment: Cite them individually. Why do you think it might be otherwise. Also, make sure you aren't violating copyright. Images are different from quoting a few words from a copyrighted text since they cary a lot of information.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31003/how-should-i-cite-3-images-that-were-used-to-compose-a-new-image/31006#31006 related

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pictures from external sources, you have to be carefull to do it right. A lot of journals are either Open Access and the images can be used under some form of CC license *with the proper attribution*, the terms of which can be found on the creative commons website. If the image in question is not CC licensed, you have to make an inquiry with the journal if you are allowed to reproduce the image and under which terms. Some require only proper attribution (they will tell you what kind of attribution they require, it will vary across journals), others will ask for payment (depending on the projected reach of the paper) and you might have to fill out a longish questionnaire to determine how much and if you need to pay. For non-academic image sources, the rules might be different.

So please make sure you get the specific terms for each image you like to reproduce beforehand, and make sure that you cite each source for each image properly and give the necessary attribution (as @Buffy pointed out in the comment)!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing between two mostly unrelated issues: 1. citation, and 2. the copyright status, licensing, and reusability of an image.

For 1, there is no question that if you include an image from another source in your paper, you should cite the source the image originally appeared in. So you should cite the images in the composite image, probably each of them individually, and also the source of the composite image if you didn’t create it yourself.

For 2, there is the question of whether you even have the right to include those images in your paper in the first place, since they are copyrighted and not licensed for free reuse. For something like reusing a graph from another paper, this probably falls under [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), but I’d suggest that you look more into this, and consider contacting the copyright holders to ask for their permission to use the images if you are unsure.

In any case, the thing to remember here is that there are two separate potential pitfalls to watch out for: 1. including an image and not citing the source, and 2. including an image when you don’t have permission to. In the context of academic publishing, not including a citation would probably be seen as (by far) the more severe transgression of the two, so that’s the one I personally would be more careful about avoiding.

Comment: +1 great answer